# Integrate a war app in Tomcat with a currently running c# website in IIS using 1 domain name/ip

Tags: tomcat, iis, war

I'm having trouble integrating a tomcat server serving a WAR app with an IIS7 server currently hosting a normal c# site. Essentially, the problem is that while the IIS7 site is up and running fine, I'd like to add the tomcat server which is currently only available locally, to the Internet. Is this possible? I have say mydomain.com currently running on the IIS server, but i'd like to have the IIS7 used as a proxy to serve for the Tomcat WAR app so that it can be hosted via a subdomain like: sub.mydomain.com/rest/api/calls. I currently have my IIS7 server being hosted on port 80, and have just been allowed to use port 8080.

Here's what I've already done: I tried following through the IIS how to from this site: [Tomcat iis howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) 
Following the ISAPI redirect steps, i'm able to get the tomcat icon logo (probably thru the virtual path), but also the IIS 404 error. Specifically:

```
Requested URL: http://111.111.111.111:8080/MyWarAPP/App/
Physical Path: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\MyWarAPP\App\
```

Part of the problem is that I do not necessarily have a physical path, per se, as the WAR file is a Java EE webservice that offers a REST service. My thought is that by have a subdomain it would not have any conflicts with the main site mydomain.com. Another thought is to have it in a directory mydomain.com/app/RESTgoesHERE

Perusing through past stackoverflow questions, I cam across some suggestions to use iis' ARR extension. Is that the correct step to implement the problem I have?

Please let me know if I'm not specific enough for anything. I tried my best to describe the problem at hand.

A few notes:

- I'm hosting both IIS7 and Tomcat 7.0.39 on a Windows 7 server
- IIS7 is already hosting the webfiles fine on the Internet on port 80.
- Tomcat server runs fine only on the local server
- port 8080 is available.
- I need both servers to use the same domain name: mydomain.com, if possible
- I'm running tomcat using the startup.bat file and have changed my registry file to reflect the suggestion based on the [Tomcat iis howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).
- Typing in my ip on any computer e.g. 111.111.111.111 points to the main IIS7 site mydomain.com
- By typing my ip and port 8080, the server tries to access the physical location as seen here as opposed to starting the WAR file: [image]

Thanks SO!